# PowerDNS Recursor cache

Tags: powerdns, powerdns-recursor

I have a question. Is it possible to disable the cache completely for powerdns recursor?
I have a problem with the domains cache. Recently a client was changing NS records from CloudFlare to other and my DNS kept pointing to old records. TTL was also very high. Where other DNS was pointing to new records correctly.

Only clearing the cache helped

```
 rec_control wipe-cache
```

My config:

```
/etc/powerdns/recursor.conf
```

```
local-address=X.X.X.X
local-port=54
dont-query=127.0.0.0/8, 100.64.0.0/10, 169.254.0.0/16, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, ::1/128, fc00::/7, fe80::/10, 0.0.0.0/8, 192.0.0.0/24, 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24, 203.0.113.0/24, 240.0.0.0/4, ::/96, ::ffff:0:0/96, 100::/64, 2001:db8::/32
allow-from=10.0.0.0/8, 127.0.0.0/8, 10.12.0.0/16, 10.13.0.0/16,10.66.0.0/16, 10.64.0.0/16
forward-zones=admin=X.X.X.X:53
max-negative-ttl=300
dnssec=off
```

I added max-cache-ttl=900 now. But I don't know if this will solve the problem.